# Hashing std::vector independent of items order

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, hash

I am looking for a hash function for `std::vector`, which would be independent from vector's item's ordering.

In other words I am looking for a hash implementation,
that would give me same result for

```
std::vector<int> v1(1,2,3);
std::vector<int> v2(2,3,1);
std::vector<int> v3(1,3,2);
```

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Slow but ... in the hash function sort into a temporary vector and generate the hash from that.  Hash each element and then combine the hashes.  Or just keep your original vector sorted.

Comment: Depending on the quality of the hash function desired, any of the following hash functions will work: adding all `int`s together; exclusive-oring all `int`s together.

Comment: @RichardCritten , I can't do that since my target is o(1) insertion

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , curretnly using seed ^= i + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2); I am adding them together, but the result depends on the order.

Comment: I suggested ***either*** addition or xor. Using both like that, of course won't work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , but in that case generated hash would be the same for 1,2,3 and say 1,1,4 as both have sum = 6.  I am misunderstanding something? It would be much clear if you provide an example

Comment: A hash function, by definition will always be non-unique. If you find a hash function that can produce a different 32 bit value for any combination of three 32 bit values, you are guaranteed for a Nobel prize in mathematics.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik , yes, but people are looking for the ones where collisions could be as few as possible. btw, there is no nobel prize in mathematics ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<template<class...>class element_hash=std::hash>
struct symmetric_range_hash {
  template<class T>
  std::size_t operator()( T const& t ) const {
    std::size_t r = element_hash<int>{}(0); // seed with the hash of 0.
    for (auto&& x:t) {
      using element_type = std::decay_t<decltype(x)>;
      auto next = element_hash<element_type>{}(x);
      r = r + next;
    }
    return r;
  }
};
```

That should do it.  We gather the hashes via `+` which is symmetric.

`+` is better than `^` because it takes longer to get a cycle.  With `^`, `{1,1}` and `{2,2}` would hash the same (and in general even numbers of anything "disappear").  With `+` they instead get multiplied.

So the end result is the sum, for each distinct value in the array, of the hash of that value times its count, mod "max(size_t)+1".

Note that an `unordered_map` requires both a hash and an equality.  If you want collision, you'll need to also write an `==`.

```
struct unordered_equal {
  template<class C>
  bool operator()(C const& lhs, C const& rhs)const {
    using std::begin;
    using K = std::decay_t< *decltype(begin(lhs)) > >;
    std::unordered_map< K, std::size_t > counts;
    for (auto&& k : lhs) {
      counts[k]++;
    }
    for (auto&& k : rhs) {
      counts[k]--;
    }
    for (auto&& kv : counts)
      if (kv.second != 0) return false;
    return true;
  }
};
```

Comment: @Yakk , Thanks for the geneneric code, but I still could not put that into ordererd_map, would you please help? 

std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>,int symmetric_range_hash<std::vector<int> > > m;

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, same here :))))

Comment: @libxelar.so Just use `symmetric_range_hash<>`.  It is transparent, you don't have to pass in what you are hashing, but rather what you use to hash the *elements* from their type.  It defaults to using `std::hash<T>` if the elements are `T`s.

Comment: @Yakk thanks for the help but It does not work.

std::unordered_map<std::vector<int>,int,symmetric_range_hash<>> m;    
    
std::vector<int> v(3);
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
    
std::vector<int> v1(3);
v1.push_back(2);
v1.push_back(1);
v1.push_back(3);

m[v1]=555;
m[v]=555;

std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;

Comment: Perhaps this answer would be easier to understand if a concrete solution for `std::hash<int>` was presented first and only *then* made generic as a nice-to-have feature, perhaps even in two steps (first the `int` turned into the template argument, then the `std::hash` into the template template argument).

Comment: @ChristianHackl , agree but code logic is straightforward, as it just summing per value hashes

Comment: @Yakk: can you please give a comment about the choice of `+`? Why not any other symmetric function `f(x_1,...,x_N)` ... is it just because it's simple? I mean, in `hash_combine` snippets here on SO (where order usually matters), one never encounters such a simple approach.

Comment: @davidhigh You usually want to avoid symmetry with a hash combine.  Here we want it.

Comment: @libxelar.so Unordered maps use both hash and ==; hash collision is not enough to cause equality.  This is unrelated to the hashing operation.

Comment: @libxelar.so [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/651a1934743bd624) is an implementation that dumbly trusts the hashing operation for `==`.  In reality, `==` would have to check that the count of each element matches in each vector.  I might create an unordered map from `T` to `size_t`, populate it from the left hand side, then depopulate it on the right hand side.

Comment: @yakk Oh , I see. Thanks for great explanation and example. Please modify your answer so I will mark it as helpful.

Comment: @libxelar.so Your question was about hashing, not about `unordered_map`.  I solved the hashing problem in the question.

Comment: @Yakk: sure, here you want symmetry. Again, why then `+` not some other symmetric transform? Is there any theoretical base on that or is it just the most straightforwatd approach one can use? For example, why not use a usual hash on a sorted version of the array?

Comment: @david sorting the array every time you hash seems insanely expensive?  It involves memory allocation.  `+` instead of `^` is obvious.  I am unaware of a cheap globally commuting symmetric operation to replace `+` with that doesn't have short cycles, suggestions?